# Problems switching from bootstrap.js or ext-all-debug / mvc loading

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs4

I'm trying to make the simplest extjs4/sencha application as possible and I'm finding that when I use ext-dev.js (as recommended by Sencha), I get 404 errors on files like:

```
/src/container/Viewport.js
/src/app/application.js
```

When I switch back to ext-debug-all.js, the app works but errors that should be thrown are not being thrown.

My App.js is very simple. it looks like this (and I load stuff in the /app directory)

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
Ext.require('Ext.container.Viewport');

Ext.application({
  name: 'EvMgr',
  autoCreateViewport: true,
  launch: function () {

  },


  controllers: [
    'Main'
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify your extjs src folder like this:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled:true,
    paths:{    
        'Ext':"js/ext/src",
        'Ext.ux':"js/ux/"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

*ext-dev.js* only includes a rudimentary set of Ext core classes and depends on dynamic loading via `Ext.Loader` to fetch additional classes. Each class is a Javascript file located in cascaded directories matching its package hierarchy.

By default `Ext.Loader` will look for additional Ext classes in the `src` directory relative to the directory of your html file. Hence the `404` for *src/container/Viewport.js* and *src/app/Application.js*.

Point `Ext.Loader` to the location of your Ext *source* files, e.g.:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext', '../ext-4.0.2a/src');
```

Your custom classes will be picked up from the `app` directory by default, but this can be changed to your likings:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('EvMgr', 'evmgr');
```

Btw, when using *ext-dev.js* there should be no need to enable `Ext.Loader` or *require* a standard Ext class like `Ext.container.Viewport` as you do in the first two lines of your code.

When using *ext-all-debug.js* you'll have to explictely enable `Ext.Loader` to allow dymanic loading of your custom class files. There is no need to set the path for Ext classes though - they are all included in *ext-all-debug.js* anyway.

Note: another common pitfall is that with `autoCreateViewport: true` Ext will try to load the class file for `EvMgr.view.Viewport`. This should be a class extending `Ext.container.Viewport`.